Notice period in Germany when getting fired with cause?
I work in Germany and I have a 3 months notice period (for me when leaving and for the company when "letting me go").
Since January (4+ months now) the company has a "2 day per week at the office" policy that I am not following. I got a special deal with my boss and his boss because I live pretty far away. So in theory it is all good, but I do not have a remote contract or anything in writing, just a "gentleman's agreement".
My question is, if in the future the company uses my breaking of the hybrid work policy as a reason to fire me (which I have little defence against), does the 3 months notice period still apply? Or can they fire me "American style", from one day to the next.
I am trying to figure out my level of exposure here. I trust my boss and his boss, but I do not trust the company.
Update: The "gentleman's agreement" is purely verbal

We have enough people fluent in german employment laws that I won't venture an answer in their way. Just to give you quick respite in the meanwhile, agreement by handshake, and then enforced by conduct (aka them not hounding you to be in the office for long period of time now) makes it extremely unlikely to make you fireable for cause for it.

Do you have a email or something else written confirming your gentlemen's agreement or is purely verbal?

@quarague purely verbal

Regardless of Law(s) etc. - the first thing I would be doing on Monday morning would be sending an email to your boss outlining the Gentlemens Agreement and get him to reply confirming that this exists and is in place. Any other answer is pointless before you have done that.

Why don't you ask your HR or manager for clarification ?

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.
That said, your exposure is quite limited.
The bar for an 'American style' termination in Germany is rather high. There are no reasons that "automatically" allow the employer to terminate without heeding the notice period, and only a few that courts have ruled are "generally" permissable.
These include but are not limited to:

Theft from your employer
Insulting or sexually harassing others at the work place
Baseless and continued refusal to work etc.

In all of these cases, the employer has to act within 2 weeks of learning about the behaviour.
The most likely 'worst-case' scenario is that if your boss gets axed tomorrow and you're beset with a different manager who's not having any of it, the harshest form of penalty they can apply immediately is an Abmahnung, telling you to fix your behaviour "or else". If you don't fix your behaviour then, they can issue a second Abmahnung, and that would be grounds for termination, in theory.
The second Abmahnung could be issued the following day, however, if e.g. you work from home Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday get an Abmahnung immediately and then work from home again on Friday.
That being said, whether this would hold up in court is another matter entirely. Since you've been working from home for a prolonged period with your employers knowledge, I'm not certain whether they could issue an Abmahnung without first asking you to return to the agreed upon scheme of 2 times at the office per week.
Even if there is no written agreement, there is most likely going to be evidence that you worked more than the 3/week home office days for months. My (non-lawyer) understanding is that your employer is assumed to be aware of this and has so far accepted it without reprimanding you. This could even open the floor to having an implicit agreement in place for more work-from-home days than what was originally agree upon, but I wouldn't dice it.

Assumptions
Lets assume a few facts first, otherwise this will balloon into a huge if-else-it-depends wall of text:

Your working contract says your place of work is the office.
Your colleagues or other people know you are working remotely.
Your supervisor knows and approves of you working remotely. It doesn't really matter whether it is in writing or verbally, as long as the fact that you do it is well known.
You working remotely is not part of your working contract.
The thing that has so far been overlooked and accepted has been going on for less than two years.

What does that mean?
In Germany, a written working contract, with a copy available to both employee and employers is mandatory.
Anything not in your written contract can be changed by your employer. While there are limits, for example those changes may not discriminate against you on unfair grounds, or target only you specifically if there are more people with your job at the company, asking you to fullfil your contract as originally written is certainly within those limits.
Your agreement with your supervisor is not a contract ammendment, and while an email stating you are allowed to do this will protect you from false accusations for the past, it will not protect you from changes in the future.
They are well within their rights to decide that they don't like this gentlemens agreement any more.
You place of work is an essential legal part of your contract. It decides taxes, public holidays, workplace injury insurance and other things based on the federal state for the address of your workplace. It is not just a fact for the curious, it is legally important.
If you do not show up at work at the time and place stated in your contract, that is a breach of said contract.
Now you are right, Germany has much stronger labor laws that protect employees. You cannot just be fired for not showing up once. But breach of contract is a serious offense. Labor laws are meant to protect the weaker party, the worker, against the oppressive bully, the corporation and create a fair ground on which they can negotiate a fair contract. It will not shield worker wrongdoing.
So assuming your boss one day writes an email saying "all remote work allowance for $jobTitle is cancelled, please resume work as stated in your contract" then that's it.
If your job is of a kind that the place of work is essential, because you otherwise cannot do your job, not showing up without informing your employer with a legally valid exception (sick note etc), thereby causing damages (most famous example: security guard, guarding a door, leaving it unguarded), can be grounds for immediate termination. "Fristlose Kündigung" (termination without notice period). That is indeed american style "don't show up tomorrow, this nice fellow will escort you off the company premises now".
You said that you can indeed do your job, so it is not a full breach of trust, just a breach of contract. That means your employer has to give you a written warning specific to that breach to make you aware and offer you a chance to not do this again.
You can then be fired as above, if you do it again. While technically, a single written warning is engough, if it goes to court the judge will certainly weight the amount of time and damages. So someone caught mishandling fire safety, getting a written warning and doing it again the next week is a sure candidate for loosing their job. Someone who is late by two minutes, gets a written warning and is late again 18 months later, will probably meet a very lenient judge that will overturn their termination. If they get their third written warning in 6 weeks, then the judge will probably see that as grounds for termination though. What I'm saying is, there is no hard limit or simple number. One written warning might be enough.
You also don't need more than one warning, if the employee declares that they will not adhere to it. The warning is meant to give them the chance to see their problem and solve it. If they declare they won't, that can also be grounds for termination after the first warning.
While not legally required as far as I know, with spontaneous changes the employee has to have a chance to react. So for example if they send an email Friday evening, that they want you back in the office by Monday and you have to secure child care first, no judge will let a termination stand because they gave you a written warning for Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, when you told them on Monday "I am very sorry, I relied on our agreement, I have to make changes, I cannot find child care as spontaneous as you make decisions, I do my best I think I can work something out to be back in the office next week".

TLDR:
So to answer your question, they can change the policy if it's just a gentlemens agreement, written down or not. You need a contract amendment. As the contract itself, that is only valid in writing, signed by both parties (unless it's one-sidedly beneficial. Raises are valid even if signed by the company only. Employee consent is assumed).
If they change the policy, you have to comply. You can ask for a reasonable transition period and not accepting that would make them look very bad in court if they fire you after the mandatory written warning.
But if the ask you to work as your contract describes and you flat out reject that, and/or have no valid excuse or plan to be compliant with your contract in the future, they can indeed fire you American style.
For the Americans: that means they still get social security benefits (not the higher unemployment benefits, since they were fired for cause) and free health care. They just lost their job, nothing more.

Expanding on @TheDemonLord's comment.  I always, always confirm verbal agreements in writing or email.
Just send an email to both the bosses, thanking them for allowing to work like this.  That email, then is reasonable proof.  If they reply, that makes it even better.
Obviously, I am ignorant of German laws.  But I have had the emails that I have sent, hold up in Small Claims Court in New Zealand.

I wonder if it's worth checking with the bosses first. If they are doing it as an unofficial thing, they might not want written evidence of it.
